Error getting file from cloud storage using Payload
after setting up my .env file with my Payload Cognito Variables I got this error in my terminal and also when I tried to deploy. I'm gettin this error before I login and also am able to login with no problems.
[18:12:54] ERROR (payload): Error getting file from cloud storage
    err: {
      "type": "Error",
      "message": "Password attempts exceeded",
      "stack":
          NotAuthorizedException: Password attempts exceeded
              at /Users/dpi-pttl47/ecommerce/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/Client.js:128:19
              at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      "name": "NotAuthorizedException",
      "code": "NotAuthorizedException"
    }

Payload build logs:
 ✓ Generating static pages (25/25)
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ unhandledRejection ExportError: Export encountered errors on following paths:
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ /(pages)/products/page: /products
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ /(pages)/reset-password/page: /reset-password
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ /page: /
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at exportAppImpl (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:607:15)
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async /workspace/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:623:16
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async /workspace/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1696:42
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async /workspace/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1543:17
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ at async build (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:366:9) {
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ code: 'NEXT_EXPORT_ERROR'
[2024-08-20T22:59:40]
│ }

I tried re-entering my cognito variables, I tried handling the fallback state with (router.isFallback)
